# Как работают синхронизированные потоки

Tags: потоки-данных, java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте! Помогите,пожалуйста, найти ошибку в коде. До конца еще не понимаю как работают синхронизированные потоки. Producent-Consument problem. В качестве склада - stack. три продуцента,три консумента. Почему не работает?

```
public class Consumer extends Thread{
      Storage storage;

    Consumer(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            storage.put(new Integer(i));
        }
            storage.getCapasity();
            try {
                sleep((int) (1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Wait until there appears at least one thing in the storage");
            }
        }
    }
public class Producer extends Thread {

    Storage storage;

    Producer(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            storage.put(new Integer(i));

            try {
                sleep((int) (Math.random() * 1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Wait until there appears a free place in the storage");
            }

        }
    }
}
public class Storage {

     int freePlaces;
    private Stack<Object> storage = new Stack();
    int stackSize = 0;

    public Storage(int freePlaces) {
        stackSize = freePlaces;
        this.freePlaces = freePlaces;
    }

    public void print(String r) {
        System.out.println(r + "Storage has " + freePlaces);
    }

    synchronized void put(Object z) {
        while (freePlaces == 0) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Wait until there appears a free place in the storage");
            }
        }
        this.notifyAll();
        this.storage.push(z);
    }

    synchronized Object get() {
        while (freePlaces == stackSize) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Wait until there appears at least one thing in the storage");
            }

        }
        this.notifyAll();
        Object theThing = this.storage.pop();
        return theThing;
    }
    void getCapasity(){
        System.out.println("The storage has"+storage.capacity()+"by the moment");
    }
}
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Storage s = new Storage(0);
        Producer p1 = new Producer(s); 
        Producer p2 = new Producer(s);
        Producer p3 = new Producer(s);
        Consumer c1 = new Consumer(s);
        Consumer c2 = new Consumer(s);
        Consumer c3 = new Consumer(s);
        p1.start();
        p2.start();
        p3.start();
        c1.start();
        c2.start();
        c3.start();
        p1.join();
        p2.join();
        p3.join();
        c1.join();
        c2.join();
        c3.join();
        s.print("END");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала и без потоков есть проблема, т.к. и consumer и producer добавляют значения на стек, но никто их не потребляет. По идее это должен делать consumer.